# How can I let the plane collide with an object in RealityKit

Tags: swift, swiftui, realitykit

I have a ball and a plane (floor) in `realityKit`.
The ball falls and has to `collide` on the plane. But the ball is `falling` `through` the plane. When the ball hits the plane i want a print statement "OCCURED" but this is also not happening.

My code:

```
struct ARViewContainer: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    let arView = ARView(frame: .zero)
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ARView {

        var subscriptions: [Cancellable] = []
        
        let anchor = AnchorEntity()
    
        //generate a plane
        let planeModel = ModelEntity(mesh: .generatePlane(width: 2.0, 
                                    depth: 2.0))
        as (Entity & HasCollision)
       
        planeModel.position = [0,-10,-1.5]
        planeModel.generateCollisionShapes(recursive: true)
        
        //generate a ball
        let ballModel = ModelEntity(mesh: .generateSphere(radius: 0.4))
                                 as (Entity & HasCollision & HasPhysicsBody)
        ballModel.generateCollisionShapes(recursive: true)
        ballModel.position = [0,0, -1.5]
        
        ballModel.physicsBody = .init()
        ballModel.physicsBody?.mode = .dynamic
        
        let sub = arView.scene.subscribe(to: CollisionEvents.Began.self,
                                on: ballModel) { _ in print("OCCURED!") }
        subscriptions.append(sub)
        
        anchor.addChild(ballModel)
        anchor.addChild(planeModel)
        arView.scene.addAnchor(anchor)
        
        return arView
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Collider and collidee

This code activates physics and prints `"occured"` N times, thanks to CollisionEvents' subscription:

```
import SwiftUI
import RealityKit
import Combine

struct ARViewContainer: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    @State var subscriptions: [AnyCancellable] = []
    let arView = ARView(frame: .zero)
    let anchor = AnchorEntity()
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ARView {

        // PLANE
        let planeModel = ModelEntity(mesh: .generatePlane(width: 2.0,
                                                          depth: 2.0)) 
                                                   as (Entity & HasPhysics)
       
        planeModel.position = [0,-1,-1.5]
        planeModel.generateCollisionShapes(recursive: false)
        planeModel.physicsBody = .init()
        planeModel.physicsBody?.mode = .static
        
        // BALL
        let ballModel = ModelEntity(mesh: .generateSphere(radius: 0.2), 
                               materials: [UnlitMaterial()])
                                                   as (Entity & HasPhysics)

        ballModel.position = [0, 1,-1.5]
        ballModel.generateCollisionShapes(recursive: false)            
        ballModel.physicsBody = .init()
        ballModel.physicsBody?.mode = .dynamic
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {

            arView.scene.subscribe(to: CollisionEvents.Began.self,
                                   on: ballModel) { _ in
                print("OCCURED!")
                
            }.store(in: &subscriptions)
        }    
        anchor.addChild(ballModel)
        anchor.addChild(planeModel)
        arView.scene.addAnchor(anchor)           
        return arView
    }
    func updateUIView(_ view: ARView, context: Context) { }
}

struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
        ARViewContainer().ignoresSafeArea()
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: tx, slowly progress on my side :). The difference in model creation in your code is "HasPhysics" where in my code this is "HasPhysicsBody". What is exactly the difference between does two ?

Comment: `HasPhysics` conforms to HasPhysicsBody and HasPhysicsMotion. `HasPhysicsBody` conforms to `HasCollision`. But it's not the key. The key is `.store(in: &subscriptions)` method with parameter of [AnyCancellable] type.

Comment: @saro, have you tried this code?

Comment: yep, thats working fine, but in the other project iam trying MVVM setup with the ontapgesture of swiftui. Everything is working well except the collision detection. It looks like something is wrong with the subscriptions

Comment: What's your code? Publish it as another question.