# Get collision component of source Blender model

Tags: swift, arkit, realitykit

I have a `blender import` model with a simple `plane` with `cylinders` on it.
Now i want a `collision component` on the cylinders.

The imported model and children form blender printed out if i start the app. This is working fine but no collision on the cylinders

```
▿ '/' : Entity, children: 1
  ⟐ Transform
  ⟐ SynchronizationComponent
  ▿ 'cilinders' : Entity, children: 6
    ⟐ Transform
    ⟐ SynchronizationComponent
    ▿ 'Light' : Entity
      ⟐ Transform
      ⟐ SynchronizationComponent
    ▿ 'Camera' : Entity
      ⟐ Transform
      ⟐ SynchronizationComponent
    ▿ 'Plane' : Entity, children: 1
      ⟐ Transform
      ⟐ SynchronizationComponent
      ▿ 'Plane_geometry' : ModelEntity
        ⟐ Transform
        ⟐ ModelComponent
        ⟐ SynchronizationComponent
    ▿ 'Cylinder' : Entity, children: 1
      ⟐ Transform
      ⟐ SynchronizationComponent
      ▿ 'Cylinder_geometry' : ModelEntity
        ⟐ Transform
        ⟐ ModelComponent
        ⟐ SynchronizationComponent
    ▿ 'Cylinder_001' : Entity, children: 1
      ⟐ Transform
      ⟐ SynchronizationComponent
      ▿ 'Cylinder_001_geometry' : ModelEntity
        ⟐ Transform
        ⟐ ModelComponent
        ⟐ SynchronizationComponent
    ▿ 'Cylinder_002' : Entity, children: 1
      ⟐ Transform
      ⟐ SynchronizationComponent
      ▿ 'Cylinder_002_geometry' : ModelEntity
        ⟐ Transform
        ⟐ ModelComponent
        ⟐ SynchronizationComponent
```

I want the cylinders to collide so here my code for that, this is for one cylinder:

```
let cylinder1 = importModel.children[0].children[3].children[0] as! ModelEntity
cylinder1.generateCollisionShapes(recursive: false)
```

And the add it to collision events:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    arView.scene.subscribe(to: CollisionEvents.Began.self,
                           on: cylinder1) { _ in
        print("Collision ball detected!")

    }.store(in: &self.subscriptions)  
}
```

Collision is not working. What am I missing here?

Comment: https://dropmefiles.com/xAnHt  ik dropped it.

Comment: Please, publish it as another question. Do not edit questions after they have been answered. It's forbidden on SO, as it makes the answer incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

My code definitely works. This answer is an addition to [that post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75178930/how-can-i-let-the-plane-collide-with-an-object-in-realitykit/75180953#75180953).

```
let cylinders = try! Entity.load(named: "cylinders.usdz")
    
guard let cylinder1 = cylinders.findEntity(named: "Cylinder_001_geometry") 
                                                     as? (Entity & HasPhysics)
else { fatalError() }
    
cylinder1.position = [0,-0.5, 0]
cylinder1.orientation = .init(angle: -.pi/2, axis: [1, 0, 0])
cylinder1.scale /= 5
cylinder1.physicsBody = .init()
cylinder1.physicsBody?.mode = .static
cylinder1.generateCollisionShapes(recursive: false)
// ...
anchor.addChild(cylinder1)
```

[image]

Comment: I cant get my code to work. But i did a MVVM setup. I mutated my question with the all of the code, the ArModel, ArModelView and contentview are under the old question code. Maybe you can see the problem, i just dont see it. In the scene there are some cilinders and a ball. I i tap the ball its going forward to collide with the cilinder. Everything is working except the collision detection of the ball with the cilinder. The ball goes through the cilinder.

Comment: Strange thing is: when the ball is hanging above the cylinder with the following code:  ballModel.physicsBody = .init() +  ballModel.physicsBody?.mode = .dynamic. The ball falls down on the top of the cilinder (just like in your preview). But when the balls is in front of the cilinder with the following code: ballModel.physicsBody?.mode = .kinematic + ballModel.physicsMotion = PhysicsMotionComponent(linearVelocity: [0, 0, -0.5], angularVelocity: [1, 3, 5]). The ball goes through the cylinder. If i need to make an other question i will do that, but maybe this is the problem

Comment: Yep, it's quite possible it's the source of the problem...

Comment: hm. yeah maybe i have to apply a force (applyforce) to the ball, i will try to figure it out. Quite frustrating